# Линейная регрессия - прогнозирование для разных групп

Tags: python

У меня есть почти 1 млн строк наблюдений по разным периодам. Нужно спрогнозировать продажи для каждого из товаров, то есть разделить датасет на группы по номенклатуре товара и для каждой такой группы построить линейную модель. Подскажите, существуют ли специальные методы для такого или нужно в цикле перебирать датасет и строить линейную регрессию для каждой? (Затем мне нужно будет по отдельному файлу построить прогноз)

Comment: Если надо отдельно для каждой, то да, делить вручную видимо. Но если они всё же как-то взаимосвязаны, то можно One Hot Encoding попробовать для номеров групп (если их не тысячи), может получится все группы разом обработать тогда.

Comment: У меня просто разные товары и каждый товар ещё на две подгруппы делится, товаров 500. Нужно для каждого товара по 2 линейные регрессии. Мне сделать onehot encoding каким образом?

Comment: Нет, если так много товаров, то `OHE` слишком раздует число фич. Но нужно пробовать. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html